# Button does nothing when pressed

Tags: javascript

I've been working on my own project for a little bit, and I'm currently working on adding another button in. Now I've set it up pretty similar to the other ones, but it isn't working when I press it. For my code, the firstx2, secondx2, and first building buttons all work fine, But when you try and click on the second building button, it doesn't do anything. I probably made a small typo or missed a line, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. To get to the second building button, you have to have already clicked on both multipliers and the first building. Thanks for your help!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click to get started!</p>

<button onclick="addPoints()">Add points</button>

<button id="btn_multiply" onclick="firstx2()" style="display:none;">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>

<button id="firstbuild" onclick="build1()" style="display:none;">Building 1. Cost x</button>

<button id="multiply2" onclick="secondx2()" style="display:none;">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 1000</button>

<button id="secondbuild" onlcick="build2()" style="display:none;">Building 2. Cost x</button>
<script>

var points = 10099;
var pointMulti = 1;
var buyupgrade = 0;
var b1cost = 200;
var b1count = 0;
var b2cost = 1000;
var b2count = 0;
var currentpoints = setInterval(pointupdate, 500);

function addPoints() {
    points += pointMulti;
    var pointsArea = document.getElementById("pointdisplay");
    pointsArea.innerHTML = "You have " + Math.round(points) + " points!";
        if(points >= 100 && buyupgrade == 0) {
        var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
        multiply_button.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
  
function firstx2() {
  if (buyupgrade == 0) {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    buyupgrade++;
    points -= 100;
    var multiplierArea = document.getElementById("multidisplay");
    multiplierArea.innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti;
    var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
    multiply_button.style.display = "none";
    
    
   if (buyupgrade == 1) {
    var firstbuild = document.getElementById("firstbuild");
    firstbuild.style.display = "inline";
    firstbuild.innerText = "Building 1. Cost " + b1cost;
    
    var show2ndx2 = document.getElementById("secondx2");
    multiply2.style.display = "inline";
}

  }
}

function pointupdate() {
  document.getElementById("pointdisplay").innerHTML = "You have " + Math.round(points) + " points!";
}

function build1() {
  if (points >= b1cost) {
    points -= b1cost;
    b1count++;
    b1cost *= 1.10;
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "You have " + b1count + " of building 1!"
    firstbuild.innerText = "Building 1. Cost " + Math.round(b1cost);
    var build1add = setInterval(build1points, 1000);
    var secondbuild = document.getElementById("secondbuild");
    secondbuild.style.display = "inline";
    secondbuild.innerText = "Building 2. Cost " + b2cost;
    
  }
}

function build2() {
  if (points >= b2cost) {
    points -= b2cost;
    b2count++;
    b2cost *= 1.10;
    document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = "You have " + b2count + " of building 2!"
    secondbuild.innerText = "Building 2. Cost " + Math.round(b2cost);
    var build2add = setInterval(build2points, 1000);
  }
}

function build1points() {
  points += 1;
}

function build2points() {
  points += 4;
}

function secondx2() {
  if (buyupgrade == 1 && points >= 1000) {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    points -= 1000;
    document.getElementById("multidisplay").innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti;
    multiply2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<p id="pointdisplay"></p>
<p id="multidisplay"></p>
<p id="b1"></p>
<p id="b2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Add a `console.log()` inside `addPoints()` to check whether it is being called or not. 2. Try moving the JavaScript code above the HTML button. Maybe the function has to be already defined when the button is added to the DOM.

Comment: `onlcick` !== `onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `onclick` not onlcick in `<button id="secondbuild" onlcick="build2()" style="display:none;">Building 2. Cost x</button>`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click to get started!</p>

<button onclick="addPoints()">Add points</button>

<button id="btn_multiply" onclick="firstx2()" style="display:none;">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>

<button id="firstbuild" onclick="build1()" style="display:none;">Building 1. Cost x</button>

<button id="multiply2" onclick="secondx2()" style="display:none;">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 1000</button>

<button id="secondbuild" onclick="build2()" style="display:none;">Building 2. Cost x</button>
<script>

var points = 10099;
var pointMulti = 1;
var buyupgrade = 0;
var b1cost = 200;
var b1count = 0;
var b2cost = 1000;
var b2count = 0;
var currentpoints = setInterval(pointupdate, 500);

function addPoints() {
    points += pointMulti;
    var pointsArea = document.getElementById("pointdisplay");
    pointsArea.innerHTML = "You have " + Math.round(points) + " points!";
        if(points >= 100 && buyupgrade == 0) {
        var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
        multiply_button.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
  
function firstx2() {
  if (buyupgrade == 0) {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    buyupgrade++;
    points -= 100;
    var multiplierArea = document.getElementById("multidisplay");
    multiplierArea.innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti;
    var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
    multiply_button.style.display = "none";
    
    
   if (buyupgrade == 1) {
    var firstbuild = document.getElementById("firstbuild");
    firstbuild.style.display = "inline";
    firstbuild.innerText = "Building 1. Cost " + b1cost;
    
    var show2ndx2 = document.getElementById("secondx2");
    multiply2.style.display = "inline";
}

  }
}

function pointupdate() {
  document.getElementById("pointdisplay").innerHTML = "You have " + Math.round(points) + " points!";
}

function build1() {
  if (points >= b1cost) {
    points -= b1cost;
    b1count++;
    b1cost *= 1.10;
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "You have " + b1count + " of building 1!"
    firstbuild.innerText = "Building 1. Cost " + Math.round(b1cost);
    var build1add = setInterval(build1points, 1000);
    var secondbuild = document.getElementById("secondbuild");
    secondbuild.style.display = "inline";
    secondbuild.innerText = "Building 2. Cost " + b2cost;
    
  }
}

function build2() {
  if (points >= b2cost) {
    points -= b2cost;
    b2count++;
    b2cost *= 1.10;
    document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = "You have " + b2count + " of building 2!"
    secondbuild.innerText = "Building 2. Cost " + Math.round(b2cost);
    var build2add = setInterval(build2points, 1000);
  }
}

function build1points() {
  points += 1;
}

function build2points() {
  points += 4;
}

function secondx2() {
  if (buyupgrade == 1 && points >= 1000) {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    points -= 1000;
    document.getElementById("multidisplay").innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti;
    multiply2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<p id="pointdisplay"></p>
<p id="multidisplay"></p>
<p id="b1"></p>
<p id="b2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That fixed it, Thanks! I figured it was a silly mistake like that. Can't believe I misspelled that though

Comment: A typo is a reason to close a question :p

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your  button(secondbuild)

the keyword onclick is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Spelling Mistake. onclick not oncilck.

`<button id="secondbuild" onlcick="build2()" style="display:none;">Building 2. Cost x</button> <script>`